# Selection in .htmlbody will not accept more than one cell for copying

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an automated email which will pick up all the relevant data from a special user selection. I need it to pick up certain cells within the selection (always the same ones) and drop them into different parts of the email.

There are two strange behaviours when I output Selection.PasteSpecial to the email body, or if I only add 'Selection' to the body.

1) It gives me a type mismatch error when I select more than one cell, even though Selection is a Range. Using 'Selection' on it's own within the body produces this error (below).

2) It adds 'True' to the email instead of the data itself. Actually, I had this one earlier but I can't replicate it now. It was some combination with PasteSpecial.

Here is my code right now:

```
Sub X()

   Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
   Dim ObjMail As Outlook.MailItem
   Dim strTo As String
   Dim strSubject As String
   Dim strHTMLBody As String
   Dim Sel As Range
   Dim SelCopy As Range

   Set Sel = Selection
   Set SelCopy = Selection.Copy
   ' Set SelPaste =
   ' Set SelCopy = Sel.Copy

   Set OlApp = Outlook.Application
   Set ObjMail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
   strHTMLBody = "Hello<br>" & "Me" & Selection
'Special([Paste As XlPasteType = xlPasteAll])
   ObjMail.To = strTo
   ObjMail.Subject = strSubject
   ObjMail.Display
   'You now have the default signature within ObjMail.HTMLBody.
   'Add this after adding strHTMLBody
   ObjMail.HTMLBody = strHTMLBody & ObjMail.HTMLBody

   'ObjMail.Send 'send immediately or
   'ObjMail.close olSave 'save as draft
   'Set OlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: you need to build a string for the body

Comment: Hello, Can you please explain?I believe I already have built the strHTMLBody.